# Joining tuples within a list

Tags: python

I want to join a set of tuples that are within a list.

For example,

```
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5)]
```

would become

```
[123, 124, 125] 

(or ['123', '124', '125'] if it must become a string)
```

I have no idea how to do this, and searching returns little of use.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Yes, though the length may change to something other than 3, all tuples will be of the same length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> bs = [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5)]

>>> ["".join(map(str, b)) for b in bs]
['123', '124', '125']
```

use `int()` to convert if the result must be numbers

Comment: In fact, an easier way to generate integers is [int("".join(map(str, b))) for b in bs]. Oh, you got it just as I posted ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using this wrapper around reduce will handle a tuple of any nonzero length:

```
>>> combinedigits = lambda seq : reduce(lambda a,b:a*10+b, seq)
>>> combinedigits((1,2,3))
123
```

Use map to pass each of your tuples to the combinedigits function:

```
>>> data = [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9)]
>>> map(combinedigits, data)
[123, 124, 125, 12345679]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
>>> [int(''.join(str(v) for v in val)) for val in [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5)]]
[123, 124, 125]
>>>
```

note that if you want them as strings you don't need to convert them to `int`.

Comment: yes, I just stick to LC out of habit ... ;) though GE seem to be quite amazing as well.